# Converting if statement to switch/case

Tags: javascript

How can I convert this if statement into switch case? I tried to declare the variable like this:

```
myAge = parseFloat(prompt("Enter you age: "));

if(myAge <18) {
  alert("You cant not vote at this " +myAge);
} else if (myAge >18) {
  alert("Vote wisely, you are " +myAge "years old!");
} else {
  alert("Invalid age");
}
```

Comment: What if `myAge == 18`?

Comment: In addition to what @JonathonReinhart said, why do you want to make this a switch statement? Surely you only have two paths this could follow? A corrected if statement seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Yes please i want to include that also but kinda confusing. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give condition if age < 18, 
You can't not vote at this age

If age> = 18, You can vote at this age.

Else invalid age.

```js
var myAge = parseFloat(prompt("Enter you age: "));
switch (true) {
  case myAge < 18:
    alert("You cant not vote at this " + myAge);
    break;

  case myAge >= 18:
    alert("Vote wisely, you are " + myAge + " years old!");
    break;

  default:
    alert("Invalid age");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your "how can I convert it to switch" question, you can implement a function which makes **C-style comparison and returns -1, 0 or 1** as the result of comparing.

The example below uses a `setInterval` to emulate multiple different cases. 
This is only for the example.

```js
function compareTo(a, b) {
  if (a < b)
    return -1;

  if (a > b)
    return 1;

  return 0;
}


function EvaluateAge() {
  // Generate a random age between 10 and 40
  var myAge = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 10);
  switch (compareTo(myAge, 18)) {
    case -1:
      console.log(myAge, " less than 18");
      break;

    case 0:
      console.log(myAge, "   equal to 18");
      break;

    case 1:
      console.log(myAge, "more than 18");
      break;
  }
}

// Example only
setInterval(EvaluateAge, 1000);
```

Another way is to use JS `switch` ability to use **`true` in switch-condition**:

```js
var myAge = 16;
switch (true) {
  case myAge < 18:
    console.log("less than 18");
    break;

  case myAge === 18:
    console.log("equal to 18");
    break;

  case myAge > 18:
    console.log("more than 18");
    break;
}
```

However, it doesn't look good and it is a good idea to avoid this usage.

Actually, your `if` looks good and imho you don't need to convert it to `switch` - it won't increase readability / maintainability of your code.

Comment: I have made a small addition to your example which adds an `interval` which emulates multiple calls to the switch statement. Please feel free to revert if you think this is convoluting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this *instead* of concise if statements, but you can like so:

```js
var myAge = parseFloat(prompt("Enter you age: "));
switch (true) {
  case myAge < 18:
    alert("You cant not vote at this " + myAge);
    break;

  case myAge > 18:
    alert("Vote wisely, you are " + myAge + " years old!");
    break;

  default:
    alert("Invalid age");
}
```

Note, that you are not capturing a value of `18` which I'll just assume was intentional but worth pointing out to you and, also, you were missing a `+` concatenating your second alert so your original example wouldn't even have executed.